# Adding in IList using for Loop

Tags: c#, generics, for-loop

I'm have list of result as

```
var attributeresult= " some list of items......";
```

Now I'm trying to loop form result and adding into IList.but I'm getting only lastly inserting values,but I want to get all the values.

```
 IList<DynamicColumn> idynamicttableColumns = new List<DynamicColumn>();
 DynamicColumn dynamictableColumns = new DynamicColumn();


 for (int i = 0; i < attributeresult.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            dynamictableColumns.Name = attributeresult.ElementAt(i).AttributeName;
                            dynamictableColumns.Type = attributeresult.ElementAt(i).AttributeSqlType;
                            dynamictableColumns.IsNullable = false;
                            idynamicttableColumns.Add(dynamictableColumns);

                        }
```

I have to accomplish with for loop only not with for each loop.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You won't do yourself any favor when you try to add contents during a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Move `DynamicColumn dynamictableColumns = new DynamicColumn();` into your loop:

```
IList<DynamicColumn> idynamicttableColumns = new List<DynamicColumn>();
int count = attributeresult.Count();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var item = attributeresult.ElementAt(i);
    DynamicColumn dynamictableColumns = new DynamicColumn();
    dynamictableColumns.Name = item .AttributeName;
    dynamictableColumns.Type = item .AttributeSqlType;
    dynamictableColumns.IsNullable = false;
    idynamicttableColumns.Add(dynamictableColumns);
}
```

Comment: Adding an explanation: The problem is that you only create ony object, and then keep editing the properties of that object; it's still the very same object you keep adding to your list. This fix creates a new object for every iterating instead.

Comment: While you're fixing OP's code, could you also replace the repeated use of `Count()` and `ElementAt(i)` with a `foreach` loop? It's potentially a massive performance hit.